# play uploaded video facebook application

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

this may be a dumb question , but how would one play a facebook hosted video, uploaded by 
Facebook C# SDK , from within a facebook application?

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to get information such as VIDEO_ID, link, picture the most recent video my application uploads but I can't seem to locate were they are being uploaded to.

Below is my GET graph request for uploading the video. It would make sense if the video was located at https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/videos/ or something alone those lines. but it isn't anywhere to be found.

```
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/343226535752652/videos?"
. "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc 
. "&". $access_token;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depends on the C# SDK. I guess you will need to get the source of the video from the Graph API: https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID?fields=source&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

I haven't tried it but I would proceed like that.